# Compressing large C++ std::strings in memory

Tags: c++, linux, database, compression

I am writing a utility in C++ that will examine Versant Object Databases for errors. Dumping the DB to text for simpler parsing is done, but these DBs can easily break 20GB and our Linux backend jumpbox does not have enough RAM for this. Additionally, each of us admins is limited to 1GB of HDD space. As string arrays in each object instance are filled with data for analysis, I need to compress the data. What would be a fairly simple way to accomplish this, please?

Comment: The solution is not to get the whole database at once, but take one "object" at a time and analyze it. If objects references other objects, load only the ones needed and no more.

Comment: Can you obtain only subsets of data at a time? Even if you manage to compress the data, how are you going to perform analyses on it in the compressed form?

Comment: Search the web for "lossless compression" to find algorithms for compressing data.

Comment: Can you store the strings as BLOB data and tell the database to handle the compression?

Comment: The databases are highly normalized and have instances of objects that have arrays of other instances that may exist in other objects. For example, an instance of a customer object contains references to instances of transaction objects, phone number objects, address objects, etc. Thus, I cannot only analyze one instance or object at a time. The entire DB must be loaded into memory for analysis.

I think incorporating compression into the class would suffice.